# jtextpane cursor at end after new line is different size

Tags: java, swing, size, jtextpane, caret

My users found that if the last character in a `JTextPane` is a newline, the cursor is smaller.  Debug statements showed the same cursor and the same font no matter where I clicked.  I downloaded the `Oracle` demo for `JTextPane` and can see the same behaviour, so it appears to be out of the box behaviour.

Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

> My users found that if the last character in a JTextPane is a newline, the cursor is smaller

The caret represents the height of the largest Font used on the line. Since there is no text a smaller caret is used. Is this really an issue to worry about?

> I downloaded the Oracle demo for JTextPane and can see the same behaviour

Add the following line of code to the TextComponentDemo:

```
Rectangle caretCoords = textPane.modelToView(dot);
System.out.println(caretCoords); // added
```

You will see that the height changes. The height of the Rectangle is used by the `DefaultCaret` class to paint the caret.

I guess you could override the `modelToView(...)` method of `JTextPane` to return a minimum height based on the FontMetrics of the Font of the text pane. Not sure what other functionality of the text pane that might affect.

Or you could override the `paint()` method of the `DefaultCaret` to use a minimum height, again based on the FontMetrics.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I agree it's not an issue to worry about, but next time there are no more pressing issues, I do appreciate your suggestions to make the user happy.